# "Maintenance" or "Support"?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, software

I would like to differentiate between free basic support services, included in the License (Software) and additional paid support services. In which case should I use 'Support'  and in which 'Maintenance'?  Are there other applicable terms with the same meaning?

Comment: Maintenance is about routine procedures, such as upgrading software, making backups etc. Support is about helping users operate the system, for tasks they should be able to do themselves but for whatever reason they cannot do it.

Answer (score 1):

In the IT industry, those terms have different meanings:

**Maintanance** is a phase in software production. The software is generally ready, you fix errors and add new features. This is done internally, within software company.

**Support** is something that is done externally and it's relevant to external customers. Support is a service in which consultants help customers with installation, configuration and usage of the software. They can also provide modifications on demand (which will be handled internally as maintanance).

Answer (score 0):

## Maintenance:

This is resolving errors and introducing additional features to prevent errors. This is something to be done before the release of a product.

## Support:

After the release when your product is used by customers and they complaint some thing, support is to resolve those issues. Usually developers are not involved in this.
The complaints are mainly coz of malfunctioning not a missing feature.

- support only works on complaints while maintenance not always.

in the given case, it will be the term "support" for both the only difference is in paid case, if needed your query could be escalated to development team to design a user specific patch to make the things working.